# Как реализовать регистрацию и авторизации пользователя на сайте с помощью смс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать регистрацию и авторизацию пользователя на сайт с помощью номера телефона. Например, как в Телеграм. Может уже есть готовые решения для Django?

Comment: Самом процесс регистрации такой же как и при регистрации через email, только подтверждаться будет номер телефона. Можно воспользоваться api от smscenter, и их библиотекой для python https://smsc.ru/api/code/libraries/http_smtp/python/#menu.

Answer (score 2):

Для авторизации через Telegram, можно использовать готовый модуль:
[django-telegram-login](https://github.com/dmytrostriletskyi/django-telegram-login).